# Angular ng serve does not work as expected

Tags: node.js, json, angular, npm, package.json

I am trying to run my angular application but facing issue while running the application using **ng serve**.
The ng build works fine but the ng server does not work (Did try with **npm start** as well)
[ngserve response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4686d.png)

1. Did try adding a proxy.conf.json under root folder(app folder)
   then updated the package.json start : "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json"
2. Did try adding a prxy.conf.js under root folder(app folder)
   then updated the package.json start : "ng serve --proxy-config=proxy.conf.js"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to error in screen you attached, it seems like you shouldn't put `proxy.conf.js` in `src`, but in project root directory. In your case its name is: `LoupeUS-Frontend`

Comment: Yes this did work.
Created a proxy.conf.js in the Root folder and updated package.json start : "ng serve --proxy-config=proxy.conf.js"
 
For running application i used the command npm start.

Is there any way to use the ng server(was not able to use ng serve to run the application)

Comment: can you show what console shows up when you type `ng serve`?

Comment: Similar error message as earlier..........
- Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...An unhandled exception occurred: Proxy configuration file C:\Users\A12345\source\LOUPE\LoupeUS_New_Frontend\LoupeUS-Frontend\src\proxy.conf.json does not exist.
See "C:\Users\A12345\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-LQzmFm\angular-errors.log" for further details.